# Using reflection in Java to create a new instance?

Tags: java, reflection

I want to reflect a object of MyRow and then get A MyTable object,how should I do?

This is my java code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

class MyTable {
  private MyRows rows; 
  private List columns; 

  public List getColumns(){return this.columns;}
}

class MyRows extends ArrayList<MyRow> {//... 
}

class MyRow {
    protected MyTable table;
    private List<Object> data;

    private MyRow(MyTable p_table) {
        this.table = p_table;
       this.data = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList(this.table.getColumns().size()));
    }
}

public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String args[]){
      try{
        MyTable myTable = new MyTable();        
        MyRows myRows = new MyRows();

        Constructor ctor = MyRow.class.getDeclaredConstructor(MyTable.class);
        ctor.setAccessible(true);
        MyRow myRow = (MyRow)ctor.newInstance(myTable); // Error: ava.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException ??? how should I do here
        System.out.println(myRow);
        myRows.add(myRow);
        // myTable.rows = myRows;
      }catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

And I don't know why get this Exception, who can help me,please:(

> F:\java>javac Test2.java ...
>
> F:\java>java Test2 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>
> ```
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Sou
> ```
>
> rce)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at Test2.main(Test2.java:34) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at MyRow.(Test2.java:22)
>           ... 5 more
>
> F:\java

Comment: I think you'll find the same exception being thrown if you try to instantiate `MyRow` normally, without reflection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MyTable` doesn't initialize the `rows` variable, so when you try to call a method on it, you get an `InvocationTargetException`. If you look near the bottom, you see it was caused by a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Because `columns` is null at `this.table.getColumns().size()`.

Comment: Oh, I see now. You are right.  Why didn't I think of that.  if I could get away to let the java tell me more details,such as "NullPointerException"..That's my fault. That's was the biggest mistake